# $X$ and $P$ representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform

I wonder why the wave function of quantum particle can be represented either in the position space, $(x,t)\mapsto\Phi (x,t)$, or in the momentum space, $(p,t)\mapsto \Psi (p,t)$.

For a classic particle, observables are functions from the phase space which is a 2 dimension space with the generalized coordinate $q$ and momentum $p$ (assuming particle having only one degree of freedom). This clearly means that $q$ and $p$ are themselves independent variables of the particle.

But when quantum Physics apply, $q$ ($=x$) and $p$ cannot be used together, there are no wave functions $(x,p,t)\mapsto \varphi (x,p,t)$.

My "explanation" of this is that when Quantum Physics apply, $x$ and $p$ are paired by the Fourier transform: you switch from one space to another by taking the Fourier transform of the wave function. Then, $x$ and $p$ appear to be two representations of the same degree of freedom, which explains why only one can be used in the same time, like in classical Physics.

I wonder if this explanation is correct? at least not incorrect.

Otherwise, how could I give an explanation of this?

Comment: There's a phase space formulation of quantum mechanics as well.

Comment: Indeed see [this link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution)

Comment: "Then,  and   appear to be two representations of the same degree of freedom, which explains why only one can be used in the same time". Not quite: a Fourier transformation is a canonical (duality) transformation which preserves the commutation relation by  interchanging *x* and *p* with the proper minus sign. They are formally equivalent, but not the same d.o.f.

Comment: But then, how would you explain that the wave function cannot be a function of $x$ and $p$ in the same time ?

Comment: Because they don't commute.

Comment: @deb2014 the wavefunction formulation is *one* way of describing the system.  In the phase-space approach, the functions are functions of $q$ and $p$ but non-commutativity enters because the product of functions is not commutative: $f(q,p)\star g(q,p)\ne g(q,p)\star f(q,p)$ in general.